# Move Windows bootloader from one disk to another (preserve files)

Tags: windows-8, bootloader

I have bought a new SSD (call it Z), put it in my computer, and I have installed a windows 8 on it. My previous disk (call it X) also has a windows 8 installed, but now I want to reformat it for other purposes. Both have only one partition.

I try to reformat X from Z's OS, but that fails. After digging a bit, I finally understood that the new system was indeed installed on the new SSD, however the bootloader wasn't. And it is still using the bootloader from X to load Z.

On the Windows disk manager launched from Z's OS : (translated from french, maybe it's not

```
X - System, active, primary partition
Z - Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition
```

But I wanted to have the bootloader on my new disk... How can I put it there ?

In a nutshell I need to **move the bootloader and its config from my old drive to the new one**. I saw there are several Windows tools that can manipulate boot record (bcdboot, bootrec), but I can't get the command right.

Note that both OS (actually there's also a third one on another disk Y) have a Windows OS that WORKS FINE, and from which I can use those commands, so I don't think I need a windows CD, and I certainly do not want to reinstall a Windows. ALso, the automatic repair tool would probably not do what I want (and anyways everything is working fine so I'm not sure it would "repair" anything)

EDIT : [Disk management](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8EhxTyDP6M-UEVxNEZveGFQQlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `bcdboot` is the right tool you're looking for. How exactly you should run it depends on whether your system is a BIOS or UEFI one (or whether you've been using CSM, a.k.a legacy mode, if it's UEFI), and if it's BIOS, do you want the bootloader to be on a separate partition? (For UEFI it's a must to have the bootloader on a FAT32 partition)

Comment: Would be good if you can attach a screenshot of Disk Management from Z.

Comment: @TomYan Unfortunately I have already created my partitions so I cannot have a separate FAT32 partition for the BIOS. Added screenshots.

Comment: Can't access your screenshots somehow. Of course I know there is already partition. You can shrink it with Disk Management to gain some space.

Comment: I tried to access my screens with a new browser, I had no probs... Also I thought that partition had to be the first one of the disk, but if it can be at the "end" then yeah I can totally afford to shrink it.

Comment: I can see it now too. So they are all BIOS installations, therefore you don't necessarily need a separate partition. Actually none of your installations use a separate one. Try `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f BIOS`